# Is it possible to get a normal vector to the plane if i only know 3 points which exist on this plane?

Tags: geometry, vectors, plane-geometry

I have 3 points: $A(0;0;0), B(0;0;1), C(2;2;1) $. They exist on the plane.
I assumed that scalar product of the normal vector and a line which exists on the same plane will be equal to 0. Scalar product equals to $x*2+y*2+z*1=0$ where $x,y,z$ are coordinates of the normal vector. Finally i can get $x,y,z$ using a selection method. For example $x,y,z$ can be $0,1,-1$. However i think it's a wrong assumption.

Comment: Hint:  the cross product gives a quick way to get a vector perpendicular to two known vectors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us say that we have any three arbitrary points $A$, $B$, $C$ that are unique. Define the following vectors:

$$\overrightarrow{AB} = B - A$$

$$\overrightarrow{AC} = C - A$$

which both lie along the plane that contains the three points. Now we form the normal vector by using the cross product:

$$\overrightarrow{AB} \times \overrightarrow{AC}$$

which is guaranteed to be perpendicular to the two above.

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are enough points to define a plane, there **will** exist a normal vector to the plane; as a matter of fact, a plane is defined by 
$$
\vec{N}\cdot\left( \vec{a} + \vec{b} \right) = 0
$$
Where $\vec{a}$ and $\vec{b}$ are vectors that go from one point in space to another. We call the vector $\vec{N}$ that satisfies the above a *normal vector*.

Comment: $\vec a+\vec b$ is not generally in the plane where $\vec a$ and $\vec b$ point to distinct points on the plane.  The general scalar equation of a plane is $\vec N\cdot (\vec x - \vec x_0)=0$

Comment: Two vectors always define a plane, as long as they have non-zero magnitude and are not parallel to each other.

Comment: They define a plane through the origin.  OP's plane does happen to contain the origin, but I consider it misleading not to write it in the more general form.

Comment: The vectors I used in my answer are just for representative purposes; they are not the vectors of the question. His question is if "it was possible to make a plane with three points", and I wrote the scalar equation, for it is simple to deduce that the least amount of points that can create two vectors that follow the above is three.

Comment: I've removed the downvote, but I still consider your answer misleading.